# Asking multiple questions successively and grammar structure

Tags: questions, inversion

> Do you see where I am coming from or my idea is still not clear?

> Do you see where I am coming from or is my idea still not clear

I was thinking which is more grammatically correct, I know that, in a question, the other verbs following the main verb, that got inverted, doesn't need inversion (this has a grammatical name but I can't find it) however I'm confused wether to consider the sentence after *or* a new question or not.

Are both forms grammatical but with a slight difference in meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking two independent questions:

> Do you see where I am coming from?
> Is my idea still not clear?

You are combining them with the coordinating conjunction “or”, which requires a comma:

> Do you see where I am coming from, or is my idea still not clear?

Each question is still an independent clause, so they still both need their subject-verb inversion.